# How to delete a file with an empty name from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, delete-file

Somehow, using the AWS Java API, we managed to upload a file to S3 without a name.

The file is shown if we run `s3cmd ls s3://myBucket/MyFolder`, but is not shown in the S3 GUI.

Running `s3cmd del s3://myBucket/MyFolder/` give the following error:

```
ERROR: Parameter problem: Expecting S3 URI with a filename or --recursive: s3://myBucket/MyFolder/
```

Running the same command without the trailing slash does nothing.

How can the file be deleted?

Comment: I think you could move all of the files from this folder to another new folder excluding your bad file then remove all of the folder content using  aws s3 rm --force -R s3://myBucket/MyFolder/ .. but if you have so many files there it will be a problem maintaining this :( how many files do u have inside ur folder?

Comment: @msoliman The folder has sub folders. There's lots of data there that can't really be moved.

Comment: Are you sure it's not in the gui?  If it really isn't, you may need to use the API to do a `ListObjects` and figure out what the actual key is, since it can't actually be nothing.  It might be that `MyFolder//` would get it, but use caution, of course.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot `MyFolder//` gives the same error as with a single slash.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know, it can't be done using s3cmd.

It *can* be done using the aws cli, by running:

```
aws s3 rm 3://myBucket/MyFolder/
```

Make sure you don't use the `--recursive` flag, or it will remove the entire directory.