# How to upload a file to S3 without a name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am reading data from S3 bucket using Athena and the data from following file is correct.

```
# aws s3 ls --human s3://some_bucket/email_backup/email1/
2020-08-17 07:00:12    0 Bytes
2020-08-17 07:01:29    5.0 GiB email_logs_old1.csv.gz
```

When I change the path to _updated as shown below, I get an error.

```
# aws s3 ls --human s3://some_bucket/email_backup_updated/email1/
2020-08-22 12:01:36    5.0 GiB email_logs_old1.csv.gz
2020-08-22 11:41:18    5.0 GiB
```

This is because of the extra file without name in the same location. I have no idea how I managed to upload a file without a name. I will like to know how to repeat it (so that I can avoid it)

Comment: Similar but not duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753269/how-to-delete-a-file-with-an-empty-name-from-s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an extra **non-breaking space** at the end of the destination path, the file will be copied to S3 but with a blank name. for e.g.

```
aws s3 cp t.txt s3://some_bucket_123/email_backup_updated/email1/
```

(Note the non-breaking space after email1/ )

\xa0 is actually non-breaking space in Latin1, also chr(160). The non breaking space itself is the name of the file!

Using the same logic, I can remove the "space" file by adding the non-breaking space at the end.

```
aws s3 rm  s3://some_bucket_123/email_backup_updated/email1/
```

I can also login to console and remove it from User Interface.

Comment: I also had success in Windows using quotes and a regular space e.g. `"s3://some_bucket_123/email_backup_updated/email1/ "`

Answer (score 1):

All S3 files have a name (in fact the full path is actually the object key, which is the metadata to define your object name).

If you see a blank named file in the path of `s3://some_bucket/email_backup_updated/email1/` you have likely created a file named `s3://some_bucket/email_backup_updated/email1/`.

As I mentioned earlier S3 objects use key, for this reason the file hierarchy does not exist. You simply are filtering by prefix instead.

You should be able to validate this by performing the following without the trailing slash `aws s3 ls --human s3://some_bucket/email_backup_updated/email1`.

Comment: I am using aws s3 cp linux command. I have checked the history and I could not find the command that uploaded the wrong object key. Can you share a command to reproduce this?

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce that scenario just using `aws s3 cp` from a file on disk, although I can reproduce it using `aws s3api put-object --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key this/looks/like/a/folder/subfolder/ --body test.txt`. If I run `aws s3 ls --human s3://$BUCKET_NAME/this/looks/like/a/folder/subfolder/` I see a blank file name.

Comment: The only way I could reproduce this using aws s3 cp is by copying a file already using a `/` name.